# Count of several keywords on a site

Tags: grep, wget

I currently have the following command

```
wget -O - -q http_url_goes_here |
    grep -Eci '(cart|shop|buy|order|store|shipping|products|price)'
```

It gives me a count of ALL occurences of each of the following keywords on the site `(cart|shop|buy|order|store|shipping|products|price)`.

The problem I have is that I get counts as high as 200 if some of the words occur multiple times. I would like to get a count of between 0 and 8, which would indicate how many of the keywords were found on the site. As in the count should be incremented by a maximum of 1 for each keyword.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
wget -O - -q http_url_goes_here |
    grep -wEoi 'cart|shop|buy|order|store|shipping|products|price' | 
        sort -fu | wc -l
```

I added the `-w` to your `grep` command so that you don't count, for example, bishop as a hit for shop.

Comment: Thank you very much. And thanks to everyone else as well..

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]_' '[\n*]' | grep -xiF 'cart
shop
buy
order
store
shipping
products
price' | sort -fu | wc -l
```

You can also have the list of words in a file and use:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]_' '[\n*]' | grep -xiFf word.list | sort -fu | wc -l
```

You can possibly make it more efficient by doing:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]_' '[\n*]' | awk -v o=0 '
   {$0=tolower($0)}
   NR==FNR{a[$0];n++;next}
   {
     for (i in a) if ($0 == i) {
       if (++o == n) exit
       delete a[i]
     }
   }
   END {print o}' word.list -
```

Comment: So cool! A question, why do we need `_`?

Comment: @Gnouc, `_` is generally considered a word component (like by your `-w`), so that `cart` and `cart_2` are two different words.

Comment: And in `awk` solution, I think `{$0=tolower($0)}` should be after `NR==FNR{...} since when we don't need lowercase  word in word.list, it has been lowercase already.

Comment: @Gnouc, well we want both to be in lower case if we're to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Volker Siegel, is very useful. However if you want the output to be a number between `0` and `8` you should add a `grep` to count the lines.

```
$ wget -O - -q ix.de | grep -Eoi '(cart|shop|buy|order|store|shipping|products|price)' | sort -i | uniq -i | grep -c ''
2
```

Note that now the flag `-c` of `uniq` is not necessary.